# C, Mathematic string calculation?

Tags: c

I want to calculate a String solution. As if the input would be "1+1" the output would be 2, if it would be "1/0" it would be an error and if it would be "34-8*(3+1)-1" it would be 1...
I cannot use pointers so... It would be kind of complicated. But I don't need the solution, I need an idea on how to preform it, do you have one ?

Comment: You're going to have to parse your string. Break it into tokens (numbers and operators). Then convert the numbers to integers. Then perform the calculation.

Comment: Since strings in `c` are no more that pointers to character arrays, it would be indeed difficult to accomplish without pointers.

Comment: I recommend you to read a little about Reverse Polish notation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation

Comment: strtok and strsep use pointers :P

Comment: "why" (!) you "cannot" (!) use pointers? is this a teachers requirement? Then the only correct answer would be: "C without using pointers is like breathing without oxygen"

Comment: well if pointers are not good, let's use arrays of characters...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need a scanner and parser. The scanner splits the input string into tokens. The parser takes those tokens and does the semantic checks and the calculation. The calculation can be done f.e. recursevly.

34-8*(3+1)-1 will become something like [i]34[op]-[i]8[op]*[bo][i]3[op]+[i]1[bc][op]-[i]1

that leads to

```
   subtract(34, [i]8[op]*[bo][i]3[op]+[i]1[bc][op]-[i]1)
=> subtract(34, multiply(8, [bo][i]3[op]+[i]1[bc][op]-[i]1))
=> a.s.o.
```

Comment: I didn't understand exactly, can you explain a bit more ?

Comment: @user3195614 You need to read up on your scanner/parser theory. Take a look at `flex` (scanner) and `bison` (parser). Or, if you're lucky enough to be able to use C++, `flexc++` and `bisonc++`.

Comment: which part of the answer you do not grok? you should look up (f.e. wikipedia) lexical Scanner, Parser, Statemachine, Recursion, Expression Reduction